# Toolbar height on Lollipop is too big

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I have an app implementing AppCompat v7 toolbar, The height of this toolbar on Lollipop is twice as big as on Androids < 5.0

**Update: I'll add screenshots from Kitkat and Lollipop now**
Toolbar xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_restaurant_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/restaurant_label_action_bar_margin_start"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/restaurant_label_action_bar_font_size" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/shuffle_restaurant"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/shuffle_button" />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

My layout is as follows:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
        <include layout="@layout/activity_content" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/list_background"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:paddingTop="50dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: what is your toolbar height

Comment: I didn't specify anything, but it's something around 150 pixels at least,

Comment: show your toolbar xml

Comment: it's the first part of the question

Comment: well thats why, you have height as wrap content and your content expends beyond the minHeight

Comment: try to replace `minHeight` with `height` for your toolbar to see if this is a content who extends height beyond default value

Comment: @PavelDudka I tried that but then the content disappears completely

Comment: I'm confused by your screenshots. S4: works, Lollipop emulator: doesn't work, Nexus 5 (I assume with Lollipop) also doesn't work?

Comment: I mean on Nexus 5 it's identical to the emulator not to S4

Comment: Are you using different style for values and values-v21 ?

Comment: I found wth problem it's fitsystemwindows=true, instead I should wrap the bar in FrameLayout or smthg and set the wrapper to fitsystemwindows

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok I found the solution for this finally,

When you have a translucent Status Bar and you don't want your toolbar to go below the status bar, but instead stay in the position where the original "ActionBar" was, you'll need to set it to the following

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

But this causes the problem I described above when setting it directly on the ToolBar, so instead I wrapped the toolbar in

```
<FrameLayout />
```

and set the

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

on the FrameLayout not the Toolbar